# Using Gazebo without ROS?

Tags: rviz

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I have a question.
After going through the documentation of Gazebo I am a little frustrated.
I really like the sim in ROS but for my current project I can not use ROS.

What I want to do is: Visualize a real robot in a 3D visualization together with additional stuff (like a "ghost" robot showing the goal config, little spheres indicating goal position, frames, etc).
So basically I want a lightweight RViz without using ROS.

The documentation links back to ROS all the time so I don't really know if I can use Gazebo.

My questions now are:

1. Can I simply load urdfs into the simulator (like with pybullet)?
   1a. If I can only load SPFs, is there a conversion tool? (Somehow when Gazebo is used in ROS, there are also only URDFs/Urdf-macros used.)
2. Can I update robot joints continously in a program without ROS (and how?)
3. Can I disable all collision detection (basically the actual phys. simulation), so I can spawn robots into each other and don't have delayed actuation due to inertia?

Any help would be much appreciated. I think Gazebo should be able to do everything I want, I just don't know how to get there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20095/using-gazebo-without-ros?/) by [Mr Seppersburg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6063/mr-seppersburg/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> Using Gazebo without ROS?

**Yes**, Gazebo is intended to work as a standalone robot simulator / visualizer.

---

> What I want to do is: Visualize a real
> robot in a 3D visualization together
> with additional stuff (like a "ghost"
> robot showing the goal config, little
> spheres indicating goal position,
> frames, etc). So basically I want a
> lightweight RViz without using ROS.

This **may be possible** via Gazebo Plugins in some of the later version of Gazebo.
See: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3383/how-to-add-a-dynamic-visual-marker-in-gazebo/
and: https://ignitionrobotics.org/home

---

> The documentation links back to ROS
> all the time so I don't really know if
> I can use Gazebo.

Have you looked through the [**Gazebo Tutorials**](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/browse)? Many of them cover using Gazebo without ROS.

---

> 1. Can I simply load urdfs into the
>    simulator (like with pybullet)?

**Yes.**
See: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17976/how-does-gazebo-load-a-urdf-file-without-ros/?answer=17985#post-id-17985

---

> 1a) If I can only load SDFs, is there
> a conversion tool? (Somehow when
> Gazebo is used in ROS, there are also
> only URDFs/Urdf-macros used.)

You can load URDFs directly into Gazebo without ROS, but you can also convert a URDF files into a SDF file, using
`gz sdf -p my_urdf.urdf > my_sdf.sdf`

---

> 2. Can I update robot joints continously
>    in a program without ROS (and how?)

**Yes**, you can do this via a custom **Gazebo Plugin.**
See: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5
and: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=set_velocity&cat=
and: https://answers.ros.org/question/233059/gazebo-set-joint-angles-by-ros/

---

> 3. Can I disable all collision
>    detection (basically the actual phys.
>    simulation), so I can spawn robots
>    into each other and don't have delayed
>    actuation due to inertia?

**Yes.**
See: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17216/how-to-turn-off-all-collisions/?answer=17218#post-id-17218
and: https://answers.ros.org/question/218744/gazebo-disable-physics-or-enable-kinematics-through-codecommand-line/

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr Seppersburg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6063/mr-seppersburg/) on 2018-07-26**:
Thanks so far, I will look into all the provided links when I have found time. Very thorough answer!